# How to add an element to an array inside a document that does not contain a certain element that is inside that array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, realm

$%So I've been trying for a few hours now but basically I want to add an element inside of an array in all the documents where that element is not previously found. I've tried a bunch of methods such as $elemMatch and $nin but I have yet to find a solution to my problem.

**Example**
Basically the setup I want is say there's 3 documents and only 1 document has a value called "Orange" inside of an array that is located in all 3 documents but the other 2 documents do not have an orange. I want the api to see that and add the orange element to the 2 documents that currently do not have it.

Obviously this is an example of my problem, and not the usecase I need it for but basically here's the code I've used so far for it.

```
const query = payload.query;
const mongodb = await context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
const Lobbies = await mongodb.db("Sword_Universe").collection("Lobbies");
const lobby = Lobbies.updateMany(
        {players: {$nin: query.playerName}}, 
        {players: {$push: query.playerName}}
    );
```

Comment: Two things. Is what's stored in the array literally a primitive string "Orange" or is it a managed object? Second thing: conceptually, what you are are stating is that for all objects that do not have "Orange" you want them to have "Orange". This would translate to "All objects will have "Orange"", right?

Answer (score 0):

That is the wrong syntax for the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#-push) update operator.

Use:

```
{$push: {players: query.playerName}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Collection

```
 [
      {
        "_id": 1
        "fruits": [
          "apple",
          "grape"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_id": 2
        "fruits": [
          "apple",
          "orange"
        ]
      }
 ]
```

By running $addToSet it will push into array that do not have this element

```
db.collection.updateMany({},{"$addToSet": {"fruits": "orange"})
```

Result

```
[
 {
   "_id": 1
   "fruits": [
       "apple",
       "grape",
       "orange"
    ]
 },
 {
   "_id": 2
   "fruits": [
       "apple",
       "orange"
    ]
  }
]
```